# Is using a for loop with an iterator to set element at i Index in a LinkedList an acceptable solution?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

```
public void set(int n, Object newElement) {
        if (n < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        ListIterator it = this.listIterator();
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            it.next();
            if (i == n) {
                it.set(newElement);
            }
        }
    }
```

-

```
public void set(Object element) {
            if (!isAfterNext) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            position.data = element;
        }
    }
```

I have used a `for` loop to set an element at a particular index. I was wondering whether doing this is correct, the code works but is there no way through using a `while(it.hasNext())` to perform this?

I have tried this and it's not working:

```
int i = 0;
while(it.hasNext()){
     if(i == n){it.set(newElement);}
     i++;
}
```

Why does the `for` loop work but not this?

Comment: what's wrong with `LinkedList#set(int, E)`?

Comment: Your `while` version never calls `next`.

Comment: Is it okay if I use a for loop or is it better to do something like while(it.hasNext()) ?

Comment: @pacbell: As RC said, it's better to use [the built-in method for doing it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-), not least because it lets the implementation do optimization based on private information you don't have externally.

Comment: Is the for loop a better solution than the while loop since it performs less actions? When does the while loop stop? Because if you input at index 2 in a list of 100 it will do it.next a lot more times than necessary.

Comment: FWIW, both versions are incorrect. The `for` isn't calling `hasNext`, and the `while` isn't calling `next`. And a properly-written `while` and `for` doing the same thing will have the same number of operations in them.

Comment: By the way, why are you using raw classes? Is it that you haven't learned about generics yet?

Comment: Homework told me to use raw classes

Comment: That's nonsense. Homework can't talk.

Comment: Perhaps my teacher's name is homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Iterator is the wrong abstraction in this case, you don't want to "iterate" :)

In this case you should use the `List` interface, that allows access to random elements in the list (`LinkedList` is already a `List`).